# Set image to list view item onclick

Tags: android, image, listview

I am a beginner in android application development. I was going through listview today . Got a small doubt , say, I have a listview populated with string data . Now when I click on a list view item , it should set an image to the side of the text view in that particular row. Is it possible ? Please help me out. A code snippet or a tutorial link is much appreciated ! Thanks in advance to all those genius developers out here in this forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course this is possible.You should do the following:
1. you need to define a layout file for your row of listView, it should include an Imageview and a TextView. 
2. In getView method of your Adapter class, you need to inflate the layoutfile in step1, and set ImageView invisible.
3. In your onItemClicked function, you should set ImageView visible.
Wish this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro ! I'm able to set the image as invisible in getview method . But not able to set visibility back to visible . Can you help me on this ?

Comment: in your onItemClick, you should get that imageView, and set its visibility to View.VISIBLE. And I think you should also check you image are loaded. If this helps, please accept it as answer.

Comment: Sure Charles.. I'll try this out and accept this if it works out well.. Thanks bro.. Hope you'll help me out if its got any glitches..

Comment: Man oh Man !!!! A ton of thanks bro !  It worked and I'm accepting your answer.. ;) Thanks a ton bro :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. First you'll need to use and adapter that inflates custom ListView item layout.

The layout would look something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/itemText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/itemImage"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then for your list you would register a OnItemClickListener like this:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        try {
            // Open the image as an InputStream
            InputStream input = getAssets().open("image.jpg");
            // Transform the stream to a Bitmap and set it to the ImageView
            image.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Note that for the listener receives the position which can be used to open and set specific images (this example uses 1 image for all items of the list).